# How to Input / Output sound in Android?

Tags: android, audio, usb, audio-recording

I want to build a software which takes audio signals (from electric guitar jack cable) and transmits them to audio output.

At first, I guess I should make a program that transmits the sound, without changing it, to the output. And I guess this involves a Jack-To-USB adapter.

My aim is to change the signal, like its pitch, gain etc.

Any ideas how to do such a thing?

Thanks for any help :)

### P.S.

I mean live. The signal should be transmitted as soon as it is received from the USB input.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Android' MediaRecorder.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

Comment: Thanks, Buddy. Do these libraries support live playing? Like, listening to the microphone? I want to process the audio signal, as the user is playing the guitar.

Comment: Yeah look at AudioRecord. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

Answer (score 0):

If you mean *low latency* when saying *live* then there are issues, because on most Android devices you get delays between the input signal and the output signal of more than 50ms. But typically, people would accept a total latency of less than 20ms.

For your special purpose of pitch-changing the algorithmic latency additionally increases the total latency to an intolerably high value even for amateur use - as I said: on most Android devices.